# Problems with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

In `12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)`, once defined:

```
eqn1 = {Cos[t] == 0, 0 < t < Pi};
eqn2 = {TrigToExp[Cos[t]] == 0, 0 < t < Pi};
```

solving the respective equations:

```
sol1 = NSolve[eqn1, WorkingPrecision -> 5]
sol2 = NSolve[eqn2, WorkingPrecision -> 5]
```

we get:

> {{t -> 1.5708}}

> {}

therefore, through the checks:

```
Cos[t] == TrigToExp[Cos[t]] // Simplify
eqn1 /. sol1
eqn2 /. sol1
```

we get:

> True

> {{True, True}}

> {{True, True}}

Am I missing something or is something wrong in `NSolve`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you had to use `WorkingPrecision -> 5` for.

But due to your use of `TrigToExp`, `NSolve` will now do it if you add the domain `Complexes`

```
eqn2={TrigToExp[Cos[t]]==0,0<t<Pi};
sol2=NSolve[eqn2,Complexes,WorkingPrecision->5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Help on `NSolve` says

> assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in
> inequalities are real

Compare to

```
 sol2=NSolve[eqn2,WorkingPrecision->5]
 (*  {} *}
```